# Error tratar de obtener un objeto Blob MySQL en Java

Tags: java, mysql, java-8, jdbc, blob

Quiero guardar una imagen en la base de datos y luego recuperarla

He podido guardar la imagen, pero genera una excepción al tratar de obtener el archivo, la tabla que uso tiene solo un campo y espera por un Blob NOT NULL.

La excepción que da es `java.io.EOFException` toda la pila:

```
java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at practica_blob.Main.getFiles(Main.java:78)
        at practica_blob.Main.<init>(Main.java:32)
        at practica_blob.Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

He leído en algunos foros, y dicen que trate de cerrar ObjectInputStream, pero en mi código esta todo cerrado, y la documentación no da algo explicativo.

Dejo mi código para que me puedan ayudar y decir que me falto:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        File file = new File("C:/Users/yo/Desktop/imagen.png");
        System.out.println(saveFile(file) ? "Guardado." : "No se pudo guardar.");

        for(File files : getFiles()) {
            System.out.println(files.getName());
        }

    }

    private Connection connection;
    private ConnectDB connectDB = new ConnectDB();

    private PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    private ResultSet resultset;

    private final String SQL_SAVE_FILE = "INSERT INTO files VALUES(File=?)";
    private final String SQL_GET_FILES = "SELECT * FROM files";
    
    private boolean saveFile(File file) {
        try {
        
            connection = connectDB.getConnection();
        
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_SAVE_FILE);
        
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            preparedStatement.setBlob(1, fileInputStream);
        
            preparedStatement.execute();

            fileInputStream.close();
            preparedStatement.close();
            connection.close();
        
            return true;
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
        return false;
    }

    private List<File> getFiles() {
        List<File> list_files = null;
    
        try {
        
            list_files = new ArrayList<File>();
        
            connection = connectDB.getConnection();
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_GET_FILES);
        
            resultset = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        
            while(resultset.next()) {
                Blob blob = resultset.getBlob(1);
            
                ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(blob.getBinaryStream());
            
                File file = (File) objectInputStream.readObject();
                list_files.add(file);
        
                objectInputStream.close();
            }
        
            resultset.close();
            preparedStatement.close();
            connection.close();
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
        return list_files;
    }

}
```

El primer método que devuelve un boolean es el que guarda el archivo, y el otro getFiles devuelve una lista de archivos, pero este es el que da error.

Si alguien sabe como guardar archivos y recuperarlos mediante Java le agradezco si me puede ayudar

Comment: Siempre es mejor almacenar imágenes en el sistema de archivos y en la DB sólo se almacena la ruta. ;)

Comment: Es verdad, no lo había pensado así y no tenia las ideas bien claras, gracias